# umbracoBytes returns the wrong value

Tags: umbraco7

I'm using `umbracoHelper.Media()` to get a media object, and then `GetPropertyValue("umbracoBytes")` to get the file size.

However, the file size that is stored in the backoffice and returned is incorrect.

Should I go directly to the filesystem to get the correct value, i.e. is this a bug?

I've seen a lot of posts about `umbracoBytes` and I'm sure it is a problem that hasn't already been resolved.

Thanks

Muiris

Comment: Which specific Umbraco 7 version are you using? If you can replicate the behaviour on a fresh install of latest version, report it on issues.umbraco.org :-/

Comment: I'm using v7.5.2 but have a number of older versions that were set up as my project developed, so I will have a look at these too. Thanks Jannik.

Comment: Hi Jannik, I've checked version 7.5.13 and the file sizes are recorded correctly. Many thanks for your suggestion.